# Reading separate lines of user input in c

Tags: c, segmentation-fault, scanf

I have a C program which needs to read two lines of user input. The first line will be 3 numbers separated by spaces and the second line a single number. Something like this:

```
2 5 7
6
```

Here's my code:

```
int main(int argc, char** argv){
    int a, b, c, d;
    char line[256];
    while(fgets(line, sizeof(line), stdin)){
        a = atoi(strtok(line, " "));
        b = atoi(strtok(NULL, " "));
        c = atoi(strtok(NULL, " "));
    }
    scanf("%d", &d);
    printf("a : %d b: %d c: %d d: %d",a, b, c, d);

}
```

This program ends up giving me a `Segmentation Fault 11`

Comment: Did you used a debugger on it? For example `valgrind` will prints you the place where bad memory manipulation occurs. Whatever if your input data is splitted on several lines (let say 2 numbers on the 1st line), you still try to get 3 values from this line as you never check what strtok returns (if it returns NULL, atoi will segfault, obviously…).

Comment: `scanf("%d %d %d %d", &a, &b, &c, &d);` instead of.

Comment: @BLUEPIXY, answers shouldn't be in comments.  They can be missed there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The second iteration of the `while` loop will read the second line, the one with just one integer. That means, any subsequent calls to `strtok` after the first one will return `NULL` and `atoi(NULL)` will invoke undefined behavior (here in shape of a segmentation fault).

Assuming the file always has exactly the same format as the file you described, just remove the `while` loop:

```
int main(int argc, char** argv){
     int a, b, c, d;
    char line[256];

    fgets(line, sizeof(line), stdin));
    a = atoi(strtok(line, " "));
    b = atoi(strtok(NULL, " "));
    c = atoi(strtok(NULL, " "));

    scanf("%d", &d);
    printf("a : %d b: %d c: %d d: %d",a, b, c, d);
}
```